# Populate a DropdownList from database By Entry date of the item with Datetimepicker in Asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a list of customers and I am populating a drop-down list with that list from the database.

Now There is also an entryDate field in the database. Like when the customer was entered in the database.

**Now What I want is**,

I want to populate a drop-down list in another view corresponding to the entry date. Suppose I have entered 3 customers today. When I will be clicking today's date with bootstrap datepicker, customers entered today will only be there in the drop-down list.

***How can I do that?***

[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OjqT.png)

[New View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3P3o.png)

Comment: You need to write code for this. Did you write the code? What issue you are facing with that code?

Comment: you could get the date in JavaScript, then trigger a click event on an unvisible button which would load the data from database... just an example, you could try also with a PageMethod

Comment: implement jquery "onchange" event handler on datepicker textbox...and within onchange function bind the corresponding customers to the dropdown from database.......